# How to create a square buffer that retains its area in ArcMap 10.8.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.8

I've been tasked to display in a map a 2 acre square buffer that surrounds a point. This is to display a potential building envelope and also be able to reference the envelope when I am in the field. I have tried using the Buffer tool (converting my acreage measurements to feet appropriately) so the circle buffer ultimately has an area of 2 acres. However, when I use the Feature Envelope to Polygon tool, the buffer is turned into a square that is 2.5 acres.

I have been double checking the area of both the circle and square buffers by projecting the shapefiles, adding a new field in the attribute table titled "acres", and then calculating the geometry.

This answer to this may be simple, but I am not sure how to go about it. I also have not used python or coding before in ArcMap, which I understand may be the best way to approach this.

Comment: What is the coordinate reference of the map? Of the data?  A circular buffer is not going to be seen as circular in many projections.

Comment: A circle with an area of 2 acres will result in an enclosing square of 2.54 acres, and that enclosing square is the envelope of the circle.  Is your buffer distance 50.76 meters or 44.98 meters?